# Sonar scanner issue count doesn't match that shown in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I see **26,253** warnings in MSbuild log with SonarScanner (Red marked). It includes 558 compiler warnings, rest are from the code analyzer.

But, I see only **16,396** issues in SonarQube (blue marked)

Why there is huge difference of around **10,000** issues, why are not those issues reported in SonarQube !!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are <strike>three</strike> four (thanks @Julian) possibilities here:

1. ~10k issues in your project have been "resolved" False Positive or Won't Fix. Okay, this volume of FP/WF issues is unlikely, so on to
2. You have set some [exclusions](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus) which filter out some issues. This is possible, but 10k seems a bit high for that, so...
3. The number you're looking at is the total number of SonarC# issues, plus compiler warnings, plus (insert some other checker run automatically during the build here), but only issues that correlate to Rules active in your [Quality Profile](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles) will be reflected in SonarQube
4. `.cs` files outside the project base directory may be excluded automatically by the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild

Comment: None of these apply, I ran another project. It reports 4K issues, all are related to diagnostic rules, and in SonarQube it shows only 1.8 K. So, 2.2K issues are missing. It happens whenever I run this project for the first time, so there is no chance of some issues being marked as fixed or won't fix. Moreover, there is not exclusion or filter. All the rules are active in that with Quality Profile.

Comment: Some .cs files may be excluded from SonarQube if they are outside project base directory. Look at Roslyn output JSON file and compare with SonarQube.

Comment: Checked the Roslyn JSON file, they are same as SonarQube. But not same as scan log. I have two analyzer, For some files, issues reported from Analyzer A is conveyed to SonarQube, but not from Analyzer B. But the same rules of Analyzer B also works ( i.e. reported in SonarQube) for some other file.

Comment: Finally got the reason. In MSBuild sometimes one project is built multiple times. My analyzer didn't report issue for subsequent build (it was done intentionally). But issues are finally published from Roslyn output json file, which were empty for projects being built more than once (cause I didn't report issues for second build onward). So I didn't see the issues in SonarQube for projects which were built multiple times.

Comment: @Sarker I'm not sure I understand your assessment. Are you saying that for projects that get multiple times, the Roslyn output json would get overwritten on each build, so only the last version remains, which may have fewer issues than after previous builds (or even none). Is that it?

Comment: @janos: Yes, the json file is overwritten. Ideally issues should be same, even if the project is built multiple times. But, in my analyzer I did some changes to ignore issues when project is built for second.. third time. But this strategy was wrong. So, its not an issue of SonarQube but an issue of my analyzer (which I fixed).